# Lumen: add middleware to package defined routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, lumen, laravel-middleware

I have a problem with adding middleware to existing routes of a vendor package. I building an API on top of Lumen (micro-services framework created by Laravel). I am using Passport for oauth authentication and imported this package: https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport to use Passport in Lumen. I have implemented a custom route for requesting a token and want to block requests to the existing passport route: /oauth/token. But I also need the route myself in order to redirect token requests from my custom route.
I have tried to override the existing route like this:

```
$app->post('/oauth/token', [
    'middleware' => 'reject',
    'uses' => '\Dusterio\LumenPassport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken'
]);
```

But this throws a 500 back at me without Exception tracing.

I am using a custom route for requesting a token in order to set the set the token scope based on the role of a user. I am using the scope to check the role of a user (or app with other grant types), the normal token route of Passport should be blocked to everyone except Lumen self. With this only Lumen should be able to set the scope.

TLDR: How can I add middleware to package defined routes in Lumen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest merge of https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport supports prefixing the passport routes.

I added `"dusterio/lumen-passport": "dev-master",` to my composer.json and `Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport::routes($app, [ 'prefix' => 'api/v1/protected', 'middleware' => 'reject', ]);` at the end of my bootstrap/app.php.

See this issue for additional information: https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport/issues/31